# Php not working for email template

Tags: html, charts, shapes, email-templates

I am trying to send an email template with a php image generated. I am able to generate the image when I open up the file on my server but i am not able to generate the image when I send an email.

```
 <?php

//change this to your email.
$to = "Brian Chiem <brian.chiem@yahoo.com>";
$from = "Performance <do-not-reply@yahoo.com>";
$subject = "Test email - Performance Summary";

//begin of HTML message
$message = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>psdtoweb120715EmailSummary1195.psd</title>
    <link type="text/css">
</head>
<style >
{
 body, table, tr, td, p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

</style>
<body margin = "0" padding = "0">
    <table width = "100%" height = "826"margin = "0" padding = "0"> 
        <tr margin = "0" padding = "0">
            <td width = "25%" margin = "0" padding = "0"> </td>
            <td margin = "0" padding = "0">  
                    <table  margin = "0" padding = "0" width = "612" height = "826" background= "http://piqdev.myperformanceiq.com/brian/images/bckgrnd1.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;>
                            <tr margin = "0" padding = "0"> 
                                <td valign = "top"> <p style= "margin:0; padding-left: 20px; text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 30pt; color: #ffffff;font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Serif; font-weight: bold;" >Steve.b</p></td>
                                <td colspan = "2" valign = "top" align = "right" style = "padding-left:100px; padding-right: 10px"><p style= " display: relative;margin:0; padding-top: 5px;font-size: 12pt; color: #ffffff;font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Serif; font-weight: bold;"> Result summary for: <span style= "margin:0; font-size: 15pt; color: #ffffff;font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Serif; font-weight: bold;"> 8/20/15</span><br/>55 Minutes (6:00 am - 6:55am)  </p></td>                                   
                            </tr>
                            <tr margin = "0" padding = "0" height = "10%" display = "relative"> 
                                <td valign = "top" margin = "0" padding = "0" style= "margin:0; padding-bottom: 60px;font-size: 70pt; color: #ffffff;font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Serif; font-weight: bold;"><p style = "padding-left: 100px; padding-bottom: 390px; " >500  </p></td>
                                <td valign = "top" margin = "0" padding = "0" style= "margin:0; font-size: 40pt; color: #ffffff;font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Serif; font-weight: bold;"><p style = "padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 10px;">300  <br/><div style = "padding-left: 55px;padding-top:0px; ">600  </div></td>
                                <td valign = "top" margin = "0" padding = "0" style= "margin:0; font-size: 40pt; color: #ffffff;font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Serif; font-weight: bold;"><p style = "padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 42px; ">200 <br/> <div style = "padding-left: 15px; padding-top:13px; font-size:35pt;"  >3/12 </div></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <img src= "<?php imagefilledrectangle.php>>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
            </td>
            <td width = "25%"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
  </html>
     EOF;
   //end of message
   $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

  //  echo $message;
//options to send to cc+bcc
//$headers .= "Cc: [email]maa@p-i-s.cXom[/email]";
//$headers .= "Bcc: [email]email@maaking.cXom[/email]";

// now lets send the email.
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Message has been sent....!";
?>
```

The php file referenced is

```
<?php
     // Create a 55x30 image
     $im = imagecreatetruecolor(55, 30);
     $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
     // Draw a white rectangle
     imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $white);

     // Save the image
     imagepng($im, './imagefilledrectangle.png');
     imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create your bar chart dynamically then transform it into an image.

Comment: I tried to do that with php and insert as a image but it would not show up on my email client.

Comment: Did you try it on your server or locally? You need a web server like XAMPP to run PHP locally.

Comment: I ran it on my server. I did 2 tries where I just opened up the file and another try where I sent an email. When I was opening up the file the php worked fine. It was only when I tried to send the email is where I had the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<?php imagefilledrectangle.php>>
```

looks like a typo. Didn't close PHP or your quotes. Try require once too.

```
"<?php require_once 'imagefilledrectangle.php' ?>"
```

Comment: I got it to work so it looks like i needed to put in the direct link  of the image into the img tag